# MySQL query to order by parent then child places

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a table of pages in my database, each page can have a parent as below:

```
id            parent_id            title
1             0                    Home
2             0                    Sitemap
3             0                    Products
4             3                    Product 1
5             3                    Product 2
6             4                    Product 1 Review Page
```

What would be the best MySQL query to select all pages ordered by parent then child then child again if there is more than one level, there will be a maximum of three levels. The above example would produce the desired order:

```
Home
Sitemap
Products
    Product 1
        Product 1 Review Page
    Product 2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should put one more field in your table, called level and store in it the level of the node, and then sort your query by level then by parent.

Answer (score 7):

If you have to stick with your model, i suggest this query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, 
       (
        SELECT LPAD(parent.id, 5, '0') 
        FROM page parent 
        WHERE parent.id = p.id AND parent.parent_id = 0 

        UNION

        SELECT CONCAT(LPAD(parent.id, 5, '0'), '.', LPAD(child.id, 5, '0')) 
        FROM page parent 
        INNER JOIN page child ON (parent.id = child.parent_id) 
        WHERE child.id = p.id AND parent.parent_id = 0 

        UNION

        SELECT CONCAT(LPAD(parent.id, 5, '0'), '.', LPAD(child.id, 5, '0'), '.', LPAD(grandchild.id, 5, '0')) 
        FROM page parent 
        INNER JOIN page child ON (parent.id = child.parent_id) 
        INNER JOIN page grandchild ON (child.id = grandchild.parent_id) 
        WHERE grandchild.id = p.id AND parent.parent_id = 0 
       ) AS level  
FROM page p
ORDER BY level;
```

Example of result set:

```
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------+
| id  | title                   | level             |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------+
|   1 | Home                    | 00001             |
|   2 | Sitemap                 | 00002             |
|   3 | Products                | 00003             |
|   4 | Product 1               | 00003.00004       |
|   6 | Product 1 Review Page 1 | 00003.00004.00006 |
| 646 | Product 1 Review Page 2 | 00003.00004.00646 |
|   5 | Product 2               | 00003.00005       |
| 644 | Product 3               | 00003.00644       |
| 645 | Product 4               | 00003.00645       |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Output of EXPLAIN:

```
+------+--------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------+
| id   | select_type        | table        | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra          |
+------+--------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------+
|  1   | PRIMARY            | p            | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     |  441 | Using filesort |
|  2   | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | parent       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx1  | PRIMARY | 4       | tmp.p.id                 |    1 | Using where    |
|  3   | DEPENDENT UNION    | child        | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx1  | PRIMARY | 4       | tmp.p.id                 |    1 |                |
|  3   | DEPENDENT UNION    | parent       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx1  | PRIMARY | 4       | tmp.child.parent_id      |    1 | Using where    |
|  4   | DEPENDENT UNION    | grandchild   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx1  | PRIMARY | 4       | tmp.p.id                 |    1 |                |
|  4   | DEPENDENT UNION    | child        | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx1  | PRIMARY | 4       | tmp.grandchild.parent_id |    1 |                |
|  4   | DEPENDENT UNION    | parent       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx1  | PRIMARY | 4       | tmp.child.parent_id      |    1 | Using where    |
| NULL | UNION RESULT       | <union2,3,4> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     | NULL |                |
+------+--------------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I used this table layout:

```
CREATE TABLE `page` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `idx1` (`parent_id`)
);
```

Note that I included an index on parent_id to improve performance.

Comment: This is a great answer. Very helpful indeed, just used this approach in one of my projects. Thanks.

Comment: This is only works for 3 levels i.e till grandchild, on below it is showing null level

Answer (score 3):

If you have some control over the table schema, you may want to consider using a nested set representation instead.  Mike Hillyer wrote an article on this:

[Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 2):

work smarter not harder:

```
SELECT menu_name , CONCAT_WS('_', level3, level2, level1) as level  FROM (SELECT 
t1.menu_name as menu_name , 
t3.sorting AS level3, 
t2.sorting AS level2, 
t1.sorting AS level1 
FROM 
en_menu_items  as t1
LEFT JOIN
en_menu_items  as t2
on 
t1.parent_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN
en_menu_items  as t3
on
t2.parent_id = t3.id
) as depth_table
ORDER BY
level
```

that is it..

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. Queries like this involving trees are annoying and generally, if you want it to be scalable to any number of levels, you won't do it with a single query, you'll use a few building up the tree at each level.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always get it all in one query and process it in PHP. That would be probably the simplier way to get a tree.

Comment: php is not fast enough like sql!